# Why not fulfill the birchat hashachar with the leader?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer, amen

In many Shuls, the *Shaliach Tzibbur* starts the morning service by saying the list of brachot of *Birchot hashachar*. After that the individuals repeat these brachot to themselves.  Why do the individuals specifically not want to fulfill their obligation when saying amen to the *shaliach tzibbur*, rather prefering to say their own brachot?

Answer (score 1):

This practice is mentioned in the Mishna brura 46,2 14:

> ובזמננו המנהג שכל אחד מברך בפני עצמו ואין הש"ץ מוציא שום אדם
>   Nowadays everyone blesses for themselves and the Baal Tefila does not fulfill the obligation for others.

I assume the reason is because the Shulchan Aruch paskens like Rav and Rav Huna in Nazir 66b that one should grab oppurtunity to say the Brocho himself rather than let someone else say the Brocho and say Amen:

> א"ל רב לחייא בריה חטוף ובריך וכן א"ל רב הונא לרבה בריה חטוף ובריך למימרא דמברך עדיף

The Rosh explains:

> חטוף כוס של ברכה וכן כל ברכות Grab the cup of blessing [after bread] and this applies to all brochos

Comment: This, as the last time you tried to make this argument, is still not correct. The Rosh is just saying one should jump at the opportunity to be Chazzan and be the one to say the blessing for others.

Comment: @doubleaa you have not denied my post you are supporting it, in a case where there is only oppurtunity for one mitzva like birkas hamazon where one person makes zimmun on the cup of wine, one should try be the one who blesses, Here however everyone can make their own brocho and don't have to grab from each other the oppurtunity as each person will have negative intention and only fulfill themseklves with their own Brocho.

Comment: @doubleaa though it is a Machlokes Rishonim whether its better to say amen or to say the Brocho itself between Rashi and Tosfos regarding Brocho of Kisui Hadam which can only be said once in Chullin 87a. Rashi says someone who makes the brocho instead even if you answer amein he owes you 10 gold coins whereas tosfos says he owes you only if he makes the brocho quietly as saying amen is just as good as blessing

Comment: I surmise that these brachot were originally intended to be said individually at various times and events in the morning. (See Talmud Brachot - forgot which page.) Thus, it seems that there there is already precedent for an individual to do this. Only later did all of them become compiled in one place said at once. But, perhaps, the requirement is still an individual one which technically cannot be fulfilled by a shat"z. I.e., we're following the original precedent.

Comment: @danf Shulchan Aruch 6 that i quoted some of above states clearly that the Shatz can say the Bracha and fulfull others obligation if he and they have intention even regarding private Brachos that apply to each individual

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What I commented about was the concept that, perhaps, people are keeping an original minhag or "covering all ideas". FWIW, a number of Hareidi minaynim don't call up the Shat"z until *Yishtabach*, anyway.

Comment: I don't know why we need to do this again, but you're still wrong. The listeners in a Zimmun can say their own blessings at least for the latter 3, but they aren't encouraged to and generally wouldn't. And moreover why would the institution of Zimmun exists if it's forcing everyone to do something Bedieved? This is ridiculous. Please delete this.

Comment: Just a matter of interest is that why we say Barechu u’varuch shemo to discharge ourselves from being included in the Brachas ?

Comment: You could add that the Mishna Berura in Hil. Brachot mentions multiple times that nowadays we are incapable of concentrating fully; better to make the Bracha oneself rather than risk not being Yotze as a result of distractions.

Comment: @DannySchoemann give me a marei makom and i'll add it

Comment: @DannySchoemann If you always make your own Kiddush and Motzi, then that would be a consistent concern to be strict for here. For most of us, such short blessings are not hard to listen to.